# Regex expression for accepting positive and negative integers. No decimal and no more than one hyphen/ dash symbol before number

Tags: html, regex, validation, input, angular7

Where am I going wrong? I want to mainly restrict the user input to just one or no hyphen

```
<input class="form-control" required autocomplete="off" type="number" name="matrixDate" [(ngModel)]="matrixDate" 
          pattern="-?[0-9]"
          onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 45 )"
          />
```

Comment: Use `pattern="-?[0-9]+"`, you forgot a `+`

Comment: I want to restrict input just to one hyphen before the number entered in case of negative number. with this expression, I am able to enter multiple hyphens

Comment: You will be able to type anything, correct, but you won't be able to submit incorrect data. That is how `pattern` attribute validation works.